# convert price to time in minutes

Tags: functions

I'm stuck in my head. If "5" is cost per minute.
How would the formula be to find number of minutes spent based on a given cost?
Say cost is calculated to be:

- 24,6 = minutes?
- 38,8 = minutes?
- 16,4 = minutes?

This is used in EXCEL, and I'm trying to figure out how much time any given cost is equal to in time/minutes.
It is to verify that the cost converts to a reasonable time for a machine run in my printing environment.
If not, I will have to adjust some other parameters to try and get to something reasonable.

Thanks in advance for any input :)

Comment: I think I overthought this issue because of all the other more advance formulas. But by just deviding the cost by 5 should do it?

Comment: So you just solved this yourself, now?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm stuck in my head

really?

Just a multiplication

$$\$24.6\times \frac{1'}{\$5}=4.92'=4'.55''$$

That is 4 minutes, 55 seconds (..and 2 tenth of seconds)